# Can't start eclipse on a Mac OS X 10.7.2

Tags: macos, mac, java

I've been trying to start eclipse IDE on my Mac for a while, I downloaded different versions and no one works.

I'm sorry if there is something I missed.

Here is the log:

```
!SESSION 2011-11-23 17:04:56.136
----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=I20110613-1736 java.version=1.6.0_29 java.vendor=Apple
Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -keyring /Users/apple1/.eclipse_keyring
-showlocation Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -keyring /Users/apple1/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2011-11-23 17:04:56.849
!MESSAGE Provisioning exception !STACK 1
org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unknown repository
type at
file:/Users/apple1/Downloads/eclipse%203/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/81/data/listener_1925729951/.
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.fail(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:393)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.doCreateRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:282)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.createRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:41)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:109)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository 4 1005
2011-11-23 17:04:56.850 !MESSAGE Unknown repository type at
file:/Users/apple1/Downloads/eclipse%203/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/81/data/listener_1925729951/.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2011-11-23
17:04:56.852 !MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR !STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start()
of bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not create metadata
repository for:
file:/Users/apple1/Downloads/eclipse%203/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/81/data/listener_1925729951/
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:112)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more Root exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could
not create metadata repository for:
file:/Users/apple1/Downloads/eclipse%203/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/81/data/listener_1925729951/
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.initializeMetadataRepository(RepositoryListener.java:112)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.directorywatcher.RepositoryListener.<init>(RepositoryListener.java:59)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.DropinsRepositoryListener.<init>(DropinsRepositoryListener.java:82)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.watchDropins(Activator.java:532)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.reconciler.dropins.Activator.start(Activator.java:172)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:389)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1130)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-11-23 17:04:56.923 !MESSAGE
Application error !STACK 1
org.osgi.service.application.ApplicationException: No application id
has been found.     at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:262)
    at
org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at
org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)    at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)   at
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

Comment: @Am1rr3zA why did you put the whole stack trace on one line?

Comment: @Matteo I think it was cleaner this way.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA Actually Java stack traces have a format for a reason. It is stack trace and is printed as a stack (one line at a time ...)

Comment: @Matteo I know about java stack trace , if you insist on it I change it back.

Comment: * sees stack trace spans over three full screens * * pukes *

Comment: @MattiSchneider-Ghibaudo: come on the stack trace is the only hint we have to understand what is going on ... If don't want to look at it you don't have to ...

Comment: @Matteo the stack trace could be much shorter. You usually don't need to go as deep as event dispatchers. Plus, what I expressed repulsion against was presentation. I edited it (currently under review) to use an actual code element, so that it can be preformatted. Don't tell me you could properly read a wrapped stack trace!

Comment: @Matti: wrapped as in "one line" not really. I could (it's text) but I will not bother. The idea is to make a question that help people answering. If I have to read the stack trace on one line, I personally would skip the question (just my opinion ...)

Comment: Tell us something more about your Mac hardware and your Java version. If a fresh copy of Eclipse doesn't work, then your Java might have a problem (or your OS).

Answer (score 2):

It seems a problem with a plugin.

Try to start eclipse with the `-clean` option from the terminal.

Comment: I went to Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS and typed 
./eclipse -clean 
same message : /

Comment: @Zoidberg Eclipse complains about an OSGi bundle. I would try to download a fresh copy of Eclipse and run it with the same workspace.

Comment: i downloaded 5 including an older distribution : /

Comment: Ok, but are you able to start with a "clean" workspace?

Comment: hmm, it's not getting to the 'choose workspace path' window, it crashes before that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things I would try:

1. Check if I have permissions to write to the folder where I copied/installed eclipse.
2. Run again with Console open, see if it generates additional information.
3. Search for and delete the eclipse "Workspace" folder.

BTW you did not mention which version and flavor of eclipse you are running. I'm running Indigo Classic (Version: 3.7.1) on OS X Lion (10.7.2).

Comment: Hi Manish, and thanks for this answer! I edited its formatting to make it display a bit better. However, the second part of your answer (“you did not mention which version…”) would be better in a _comment_ to the question. This is a Q&A site, not so much of a forum — discussion and precisions should happen in comments. Take a look at the [FAQ](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) if you need more details about how this website works  :)

Comment: Hey Manish and thanks for your answer.

1- check, problem still exists. 
2- ran it with 'clean' flag, problem exists still.
3- it's not creating a Workspace even, it crashes before that. 

you have the same setup i do. I Checked the environment variables for anything abnormal, all seems to be in-place.

: /